# if node value empty else

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, nodevalue

I have following code but even if node value is empty or populated I get same echo = is not set or empty

In my header I include XML file which include :

```
 $linkwebsite = $element->getElementsByTagName('linkwebsite')->item(0) ;
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    if (!empty($linkwebsite)){
    echo 'not empty';
}
else{
    echo 'is not set or empty';
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the variable is populated? Try doing `echo $linkwebsite` right before the `if` statement.

Comment: Got this error - when inserting echo $linkwebsite on line 80
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in /home/mymobi/public_html/za/jvs/template/template/index.php on line 80 - whic

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it when I echo variable got error - Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string so I had to set variable node value as follow

```
<?php
if (!empty($linkwebsite->nodeValue)){
echo 'not empty';
}
else{
echo 'is not set or empty';
}
?>
```